# Netbeans Weblogic web.xml Servlet

Tags: java, netbeans, weblogic

I am using weblogic as a server. But I guess I'm doing the wrong part of the web.xml. So it does not deploy

[netbeans image(image-1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BWWY.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
  <servlet-name>ServletServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.mrkcn.servlet.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping> 
<servlet-name>ServletServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/myservlet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

> That section does not give an error when deleted
>   [netbeans image (image-2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npktb.png)

```
weblogic.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.8/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
      <jsp-descriptor>
        <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
        <debug>true</debug>
      </jsp-descriptor>
      <context-root>/WebApplication1</context-root>
    </weblogic-web-app>


ant -f "/Users/emrekacan/Desktop/PROJELER/PROJELER/Java Dosyaları/NetBeansProjects/IndirimiKovala" -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=false -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true "-Dbrowser.context=/Users/emrekacan/Desktop/PROJELER/PROJELER/Java Dosyaları/NetBeansProjects/IndirimiKovala" run
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Building jar: /Users/emrekacan/Desktop/PROJELER/PROJELER/Java Dosyaları/NetBeansProjects/IndirimiKovala/dist/IndirimiKovala.war
Distributing /Users/emrekacan/Desktop/PROJELER/PROJELER/Java Dosyaları/NetBeansProjects/IndirimiKovala/dist/IndirimiKovala.war
Deploying /Users/emrekacan/Desktop/PROJELER/PROJELER/Java Dosyaları/NetBeansProjects/IndirimiKovala/dist/IndirimiKovala.war
Deployment failed. The message was: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/mrkcn/servlet/LoginServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
/Users/emrekacan/Desktop/PROJELER/PROJELER/Java Dosyaları/NetBeansProjects/IndirimiKovala/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1058: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 15 seconds)
```

Comment: Please include error message in the question.

Comment: ı added @yogidilip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans web.xml Servet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43558913/netbeans-web-xml-servet)